# Find a minimum spanning tree

Tags: matlab, tree, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, minimum-spanning-tree

Could you please tell me why this MATLAB code is wrong? I don't understand why. Thank you so much in advance.

```
function [mst, cost] = prim(A)
[n,n] = size(A);                           
A, n, pause,

if norm(A-A','fro') ~= 0 ,                 
  disp(' Error:  Adjacency matrix must be symmetric ') 
  return,
end;

intree = [1];  number_in_tree = 1;  
number_of_edges = 0;
notintree = [2:n]';  number_notin_tree= n-1;

in = intree(1:number_in_tree),                
out = notintree(1:number_notin_tree),
pause, 

while number_in_tree < n,
  mincost = Inf;                             
  for i=1:number_in_tree,               
    for j=1:number_notin_tree,
      ii = intree(i);  jj = 
      notintree(j);
      if A(ii,jj) < mincost, 
        mincost = A(ii,jj); jsave = j; 
        iisave = ii; jjsave = jj;   
      end;
    end;
  end;

  number_of_edges = number_of_edges +1;      
  mst(number_of_edges,1) = iisave;            
  mst(number_of_edges,2) = jjsave;
  costs(number_of_edges,1) = mincost;

  number_in_tree = number_in_tree + 1;        
  intree = [intree; jjsave];                  
  for j=jsave+1:number_notin_tree,            
    notintree(j-1) = notintree(j);
  end;
  number_notin_tree = number_notin_tree - 1;  

  in = intree(1:number_in_tree),              
  out = notintree(1:number_notin_tree), 
  pause,
end;

disp(' Edges in minimum spanning tree and their costs: ')
[mst  costs]                                 
cost = sum(costs)
```

When I click the run button  says:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in prim (line 10)
[n,n] = size(A);
% The matrix is n by n, where n = # nodes.
```

However when I call the function in the Command window with

```
s=[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7];
t=[2 3 4 5 3 5 6 5 7 8 6 8 7 8];
w=[3 5 4 7 4 9 8 3 11 8 3 9 8 7];
G = graph(s,t,w);
A = adjacency(G);
prim(A)
```

The code works 'correctly'

As a final answer returns

[mst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbova.png) =

`cost=`

`All zero sparse: 1-by-1`

> It should have returned
>
> mst=
>
> 1   2
>
> 2   3
>
> 2   4
>
> 4   5
>
> 5   6
>
> 6   7
>
> 7   8
>
> costs=32

---

Why did not returned that?

Whilst running the program went from 1 to 4 though it should have gone to 2. Then from 4  to 5, that was correct but I don't know why skipped 2 and 3 and went directly to 4,5,6,7,8.

Help me please.

---

If there is an alternative code that you know please provide it, perhaps an easier one.

Comment: how are you calling it? what is the size of your input A?

Comment: Type `which size`. I presume you have created a new function with that name, overriding the default `size` function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did it, this is what appears `built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/toolbox/matlab/elmat/size)`

Comment: @nkjt I am calling it with `prim(A)`. When I write size(A), return `ans=  3   3`

Comment: @CrisLuengo Why the code does not work?

Comment: Oh, now I see: try `[n,m] = size(A);` You can’t assign two values to the same variable. If this fixes it, that is a terrible error message!

Comment: @CrisLuengo when I run the modified code says the same error message with the minor change that now is [n,m]. However when I write in the command window prim(A) return the ' correct answer' with no problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo However I tested with an example but gives an incorrect answer. `A=adjacency(G)` where `G = graph(s,t,weights)` and `s=[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7];`, `t=[2 3 4 5 3 5 6 5 7 8 6 8 7 8];`, `weights = [3 5 4 7 4 9 8 3 11 8 3 9 8 7];` For some reason from 1 goes to 4 but it should go to 2. Then from 4 goes to 5, this is correct but I don't know why skips 2 and 3 and goes directly to 4,5,6,7,8. Could you help please?

Comment: What do you expect  `[n,n] = size(A);` to do with the same output variable for rows and columns? Did you read the documentation of [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)?

Comment: @SardarUsama To give size of (A).

Comment: @SardarUsama yeah I meant in columns and rows :)

Comment: it makes no sense really.

Comment: @SardarUsama ?-

Comment: Why not calling `size` with one output and index the dimension that you want? `n = size(A)` and then `n(1)` will give you the rows and `n(2)` will give you the columns.

Comment: @EBH oh ok that would fix the first error, which is not that important I think. Could you tell me about the second error? I've thinking that maybe I'm calling the function in a wrong way..I don't know

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your function is that when you check to see if the current edge has lower cost than `mincost`, you don't verify that there's actually an edge there. If there's no edge, then the cost will be `0`, which is naturally lower than any positive cost value. You need to change the line:

```
if A(ii,jj) < mincost,
```

to

```
if (A(ii,jj) > 0) && (A(ii,jj) < mincost), % A(ii,jj) is edge and lower cost than mincost
```

Adjacency matrix used as input:

```
A =

    0    3    5    0    0    0    0    0
    3    0    4    4    7    0    0    0
    5    4    0    0    9    8    0    0
    0    4    0    0    3    0   11    8
    0    7    9    3    0    3    0    9
    0    0    8    0    3    0    8    0
    0    0    0   11    0    8    0    7
    0    0    0    8    9    0    7    0
```

The output after this change is:

```
mst =

   1   2
   2   3
   2   4
   4   5
   5   6
   4   8
   8   7

cost =  32
```

Comment: Does it return that mst?

Comment: It did not return that when I run it. Returned:  mst= 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 (1st column) 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (2nd column). cost= (1,1) 7

Comment: Are you sure your weights are properly initialized in your adjacency matrix? The only way I can see that you're getting a cost of 7 is if all of the edge weights are 1.

Comment: Yes. I changed `n = size(A,1)` too and `&&` it's correct in MATLAB and `w=[3 5 4 7 4 9 8 3 11 8 3 9 8 7];` and does not return the correct `mst`

Comment: That's the problem, then. The `A` that you get from `A = adjacency(G);` should be the one I show above.

Comment: Apparently I should have written `A = adjacency(G,w)` but marks an error that says Too many input arguments.

Comment: That should be unnecessary if you created `G` using the weights like you show in the question.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it

Comment: `clear all`, that'll erase all of the variables currently in the workspace. Then start over with the commands you put in your question.

Comment: yes I did the problem it's still there,the adjacency matrix has cost 1. I am going to ask it as a new question

Comment: My fault, you need to create the adjacency matrix with `A = adjacency(G, 'weighted');` I had assumed you did that before because you were getting weighted edges.

Comment: well it turns that it was not that the problem.