# How to set an adjacency matrix?

Tags: matlab, math, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have the following

[image]

and I would like to translate to an adjacency matrix.

This is how I did it

```
s=[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7]; 

t=[2 3 4 5 3 5 6 5 7 8 6 8 7 8]; 

w=[3 5 4 7 4 9 8 3 11 8 3 9 8 7]; 

G=graph(s,t,w); 

A=adjacency(G)
```

Could you please tell me if is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is there any reason you believe it's wrong? Did you try to [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html) G to see what it looked like? Did the adjacency matrix come out the way you expected?

Comment: @beaker Yes, there is a reason to believe it was wrong, because when given A as an argument to a function in a program, did not returned the expected answer

Comment: @beaker I've just plot G and yes it looks like the picture, so I think there problem is not there.

Comment: If you could show us the adjacency matrix you get and why you think it's wrong, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @beaker I don't think the problem is there anymore, the plot of G looks ok hence the adjacency which is predefined, would be correct. The problem lies in the answer given by the program here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568255/find-a-minimum-spanning-tree

Comment: @beaker Could you take a look in the `mst` part  ?

Comment: Why not [`minspantree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.minspantree.html)?

Comment: @beaker Because my professor told us to construct the program so I cannot use the really nice function minspantree

Comment: @beaker Do you know if there is a way to 'get the code' that builds the function minspantree ?